# Using Datagrid to display MyClass Properties (including a List) from List<MyClass> in excel style format in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a list of a simple class I am trying to display in xaml. The class is similar to this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass()
   {
      Things= new List<string>();
   }

   public string FirstName{get; set;}
   public string MiddleName{get; set;}
   public string LastName{get; set;}
   public List<string> Things{get; set;}
}
```

I then have a list of the above class

```
List<MyClass> myCollection;
```

What would be the best way to display myCollection? I've tried binding to a DataGrid, but I am having trouble displaying the List in the List

Comment: @dandadude102 it would be better if you could include what "messes everything up" refers to so your question can be clearer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to exclude Things, so I'll do both.

Without Things:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Middle Name" Binding="{Binding MiddleName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

with Things:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Middle Name" Binding="{Binding MiddleName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Things}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: The second solution with Things solves the issue, Thanks!!! Just as a quick bonus, is there a way to display the first element in the things list when it is not expanded? I tried setting SelectedIndex to 0 but it did not work.

Comment: You could always use a ComboBox instead of a ListBox and set the SelectedIndex to zero.  I'm not sure what you intend to do with the Things list so it is difficult to really give you a solution that is particular to your requirements.